# A table with advanced features

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a BIG need for help and I hope someone here will have the sympathy and the time to answer me ;).

Two weeks ago I was in training and I'm trying to add functionality to a datatable. I was thinking of using jQuery for the implementation.

Here is an example of what I have currently:

[image: tableau]

I constructed this table from C# in the code behind file. I was told to use a gridview or datagrid but the cells in this table have a feature that may not be compatible with gridview or datagrid. In fact, I add each one by a cell by specifying attribute "class" and "rowspan / colspan" when it is necessary. And I do not know if it would be possible to do this with gridview or datagrid. I need these multiple "class" for treated cells jQuery (note: to be able to drag & drop).

Here is some of my code that shows how I create this table:

Aspx code.:

```
<asp:Table ID="tabG" runat="server" GridLines="Both">

<asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow1" runat="server" TableSection="TableHeader">
                            <asp:TableCell ID="idTitreTabG_CheckB" RowSpan="3"></asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell ID="idTitreTabG_NumOF" RowSpan="2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreNumOF" Text="N° OF" runat="server"></asp:Label> <br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreSeqOF" Text="Seq OF" runat="server"></asp:Label> <br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreArt" Text="Article" runat="server"></asp:Label> <br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreQtePrevue" Text="Qté OF prévue" runat="server"></asp:Label> <br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreQteRevue" Text="Qté OF revue" runat="server"></asp:Label> <br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreComp" Text="Composant" runat="server"></asp:Label> <br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell RowSpan="2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreRestant" Text="Restant à assigner" runat="server"></asp:Label> <br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="3">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreAssignHU" Text="Assignation HU" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                        <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow2" runat="server" TableSection="TableHeader">
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreQteTotale" Text="Qté totale" runat="server"></asp:Label> <br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreNumHU" Text="N° HU" runat="server"></asp:Label> <br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbTabG_TitreQte" Text="Quantité" runat="server"></asp:Label> <br />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                        <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow5" runat="server" TableSection="TableHeader">
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibTabG_TitreNumOF_Fleche" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Test.aspx?nomColG=cod_wo&order=desc" ImageUrl="~/Images/bas.jpg" />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibTabG_TitreSeqOF_Fleche" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Test.aspx?nomColG=dat_sequence&order=desc" ImageUrl="~/Images/bas.jpg" />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibTabG_TitreArt_Fleche" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Test.aspx?nomColG=article&order=desc" ImageUrl="~/Images/bas.jpg" />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibTabG_TitreQtePrevue_Fleche" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Test.aspx?nomColG=wo_qty&order=desc" ImageUrl="~/Images/bas.jpg" />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibTabG_TitreQteRevue_Fleche" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Test.aspx?nomColG=qty_revue&order=desc" ImageUrl="~/Images/bas.jpg" />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibTabG_TitreComposant_Fleche" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Test.aspx?nomColG=composant&order=desc" ImageUrl="~/Images/bas.jpg" />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibTabG_TitreRestant_Fleche" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Test.aspx?nomColG=restant_a_assigner&order=desc" ImageUrl="~/Images/bas.jpg" />
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableCell>

                        </asp:TableHeaderRow>

</asp:Table>
```

This section creates the headers of columns

Behind C # code that completes the table:

```
protected void setTabAssignationOF(OracleConnection oConnexion, string reqOF)
        {

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(reqOF);
            cmd.Connection = oConnexion;

            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int cpt = 0;
            int nbLignesCurrentOF = 0;
            int numLigne = 0;
            string idCurrentOF = "";

            List<TableRow> lignes = new List<TableRow>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                TableRow nouvelleLigne = new TableRow();

                CheckBox controlCB = new CheckBox();
                TableCell checkB = new TableCell();
                TableCell numOF = new TableCell();
                TableCell seqOF = new TableCell();
                TableCell art = new TableCell();
                TableCell qtePrevue = new TableCell();
                TableCell qteRevue = new TableCell();
                TableCell composant = new TableCell();
                TableCell restant = new TableCell();
                TableCell qteTotale = new TableCell();
                TableCell numHU = new TableCell();
                TableCell qteHU = new TableCell();

                if(reader.GetValue(0).ToString() == idCurrentOF){
                    TableRow ligneModifie = new TableRow();

                    nbLignesCurrentOF = nbLignesCurrentOF + 1;

                    lignes[numLigne].Cells[0].RowSpan = nbLignesCurrentOF;
                    lignes[numLigne].Cells[1].RowSpan = nbLignesCurrentOF;
                    lignes[numLigne].Cells[2].RowSpan = nbLignesCurrentOF;
                    lignes[numLigne].Cells[3].RowSpan = nbLignesCurrentOF;
                    lignes[numLigne].Cells[4].RowSpan = nbLignesCurrentOF;
                    lignes[numLigne].Cells[5].RowSpan = nbLignesCurrentOF;
                    lignes[numLigne].Cells[6].RowSpan = nbLignesCurrentOF;
                    lignes[numLigne].Cells[7].RowSpan = nbLignesCurrentOF;


                    // nouvelles lignes
                    string identifiant = lignes[numLigne].Cells[1].ID;

                    qteTotale.Text = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();
                    qteTotale.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_qteTotale donneesOF " + lignes[numLigne].Cells[1].Text);
                    qteTotale.Attributes.Add("value", qteTotale.Text);
                    qteTotale.ID = "qteT" + identifiant + "_" + nbLignesCurrentOF;

                    numHU.Text = reader.GetValue(10).ToString();
                    numHU.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_numHU donneesOF " + lignes[numLigne].Cells[1].Text + " " + numHU.Text.Replace(" ", "_"));
                    numHU.Attributes.Add("value", numHU.Text);
                    numHU.ID = "numHU" + identifiant + "_" + nbLignesCurrentOF;
                    numHU.Attributes.Add("onClick", "onClick_cellule(\"" + numHU.Text + "\",\"" + numHU.Text.Replace(" ", "_") + "\");");

                    qteHU.Text = reader.GetValue(11).ToString();
                    qteHU.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_qteHU donneesOF " + lignes[numLigne].Cells[1].Text);
                    qteHU.Attributes.Add("value", qteHU.Text);
                    qteHU.ID = "qteH" + identifiant + "_" + nbLignesCurrentOF;

                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(qteTotale);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(numHU);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(qteHU);

                    lignes.Add(nouvelleLigne);
                }
                else{
                    numLigne = numLigne + nbLignesCurrentOF;
                    nbLignesCurrentOF = 1;

                    idCurrentOF = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();

                    // la premiere colonne contient une checkbox avec le numéro de l'OF
                    checkB.ID = "cb" + reader.GetValue(0).ToString() + cpt;
                    checkB.Controls.Add(controlCB);
                    checkB.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_checkB donneesOF " + reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    checkB.Attributes.Add("value", "n");

                    // les colonnes suivantes
                    numOF.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    numOF.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_numOF donneesOF " + numOF.Text + " " + numOF.Text.Replace(" ","_"));
                    numOF.Attributes.Add("value", numOF.Text);
                    numOF.ID = numOF.Text;
                    numOF.Attributes.Add("onClick", "onClick_cellule(\"" + numOF.Text + "\",\"" + numOF.Text.Replace(" ","_") + "\");");

                    seqOF.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    seqOF.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_seqOF donneesOF " + numOF.Text);
                    seqOF.Attributes.Add("value", seqOF.Text);
                    seqOF.ID = "seqOF" + numOF.ID;

                    art.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    art.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_art donneesOF " + numOF.Text);
                    art.Attributes.Add("value", art.Text);
                    art.ID = "art" + numOF.ID;

                    qtePrevue.Text = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
                    qtePrevue.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_qtePrevue donneesOF " + numOF.Text);
                    qtePrevue.Attributes.Add("value", qtePrevue.Text);
                    qtePrevue.ID = "qteP" + numOF.ID;

                    qteRevue.Text = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                    qteRevue.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_qteRevue donneesOF " + numOF.Text);
                    qteRevue.Attributes.Add("value", qteRevue.Text);
                    qteRevue.ID = "qteR" + numOF.ID;

                    composant.Text = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
                    composant.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_composant donneesOF " + numOF.Text + " " + composant.Text.Replace(" ","_"));
                    composant.Attributes.Add("value", composant.Text);
                    composant.ID = "comp" + numOF.ID;
                    composant.Attributes.Add("onClick", "onClick_cellule(\"" + composant.Text + "\",\"" + composant.Text.Replace(" ","_") + "\");");

                    restant.Text = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
                    restant.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_restant donneesOF " + numOF.Text);
                    restant.Attributes.Add("value", restant.Text);
                    restant.ID = "restant" + numOF.ID;

                    qteTotale.Text = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();
                    qteTotale.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_qteTotale donneesOF " + numOF.Text);
                    qteTotale.Attributes.Add("value", qteTotale.Text);
                    qteTotale.ID = "qteT" + numOF.ID + "_1";

                    numHU.Text = reader.GetValue(10).ToString();
                    numHU.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_numHU donneesOF " + numOF.Text + " " + numHU.Text.Replace(" ", "_"));
                    numHU.Attributes.Add("value", numHU.Text);
                    numHU.ID = "numHU" + numOF.ID + "_1";
                    numHU.Attributes.Add("onClick", "onClick_cellule(\"" + numHU.Text + "\",\"" + numHU.Text.Replace(" ","_") + "\");");

                    qteHU.Text = reader.GetValue(11).ToString();
                    qteHU.Attributes.Add("class", "tabG_qteHU donneesOF " + numOF.Text);
                    qteHU.Attributes.Add("value", qteHU.Text);
                    qteHU.ID = "qteH" + numOF.ID + "_1";

                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(checkB);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(numOF);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(seqOF);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(art);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(qtePrevue);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(qteRevue);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(composant);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(restant);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(qteTotale);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(numHU);
                    nouvelleLigne.Cells.Add(qteHU);

                    lignes.Add(nouvelleLigne);
                }



                cpt++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < lignes.Count; i++)
            {
                tabG.Rows.Add(lignes[i]);
            }
        }
```

As you can see, each cell has many attribute "class" or sometimes "rowspan". With this system, the checkbox is not related to the lines, which means that if for example I check the checkbox in row 3 and I made a sort on column 2. It will always be the checkbox on line 3 will be checked but no longer correspond to the same line.

I would like advice on the following:
Do you think there would be a solution, another method I should use?
Do you know a jquery plugin which can make this things ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure but you can have a look at [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/)

Comment: I don't see a sort function, but you need to sort by table row to solve your problem I believe.

Comment: Sorry, could you try to summarize what exactly your question is in one or two sentences?  I've read the whole thing a few times, but am still a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free but, have a look at [DevExpress's Gridview](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/). It will make your life a lot simplier. You can also use another control library like [telerik](http://demos.kendoui.com/), [jeasyui](http://www.jeasyui.com/), etc. I simply happen to have worked with them and to manipulate large amounts of data graphically these libraries save you alot of time.

DevExpress's Grid can handle dnd features on its own has well has traditionnal selection. However I think it would require some work to achieve the selection behavior you have right now.

(I tought this would go automaticaly has a comment, but hey! guess not.)